# Autopopulate cells based on values from other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'd like to auto-fill a cell using references from another sheet.

So, I've got this PO tracking spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image: Sheet 1]

I'd like to fill the G1 cell with information that is on another sheet called 'PO tracking' and looks like this:

[image: Sheet 2]

Ideally, I'd like G1 cell to look at column A on Sheet 1 (PO Tracking) and compare it to Column A on Sheet 2, and then auto-fill G1 with information from Column E on Sheet 2. I've manually entered the PO numbers into Column A on sheet 1, but I would like Excel to do all the matching work for me.

Is this possible, and if so, how would one go about writing that formula?

Thanks, 
Sesh

Comment: You want to explore formulas with `VLOOKUP` and perhaps `INDEX/MATCH`

Comment: I've cleaned up some bits of your question to make sure it's more to the point. If I've clobbered anything, feel free to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1351120/edit) it back in.

Comment: Looks good Michael, I see no need to change anything back. Thank you! Cyber, I think those might work, but using them tests the boundaries of my excel expertise...I could use some help with formula generation for them.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You'll get a better response if you do a little research yourself, first, and then ask for clarification on what you don't understand.  Be specific about the issue you aren't clear on.  There is tons of guidance on using VLOOKUP.  To reference something on another sheet, just preface the cell or range reference with the sheet name and an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2, 'PO tracking'!A:E, 5, FALSE), "")`. Not super clear what you wanted, but this works. Drag down into all cells.

[image]